# How to get the id of the application receiving key strokes in C for macos?

Tags: c, macos

I'm writing a program in C for OS X (for the terminal). As mentioned in the title, just need the id and/or name of the application receiving the keystrokes i.e. the focused window.

I've found the you can use [frontmostApplication](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1532097-frontmostapplication) but I can't use it in C or can't figure out how to do it. I'm new to writing stuff in macOS, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The UI layer on macOS is all written in Objective-C, which you can't easily call from straight C code (well, technically, you could use `objc_msgSend()`, but trust me, you don't want to do that). Fortunately, the amount of Objective-C code you'll need to do this is quite small, and you can separate it out into a separate file which you include from your C code:

GetFrontApplication.h:

```
#ifndef GETFRONTAPPLICATION_H
#define GETFRONTAPPLICATION_H

char *GetFrontmostApplication(void);

#endif /* GETFRONTAPPLICATION_H */
```

GetFrontApplication.m:

```
@import Cocoa;

char *GetFrontmostApplication(void) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSRunningApplication *frontApp = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] frontmostApplication];

        return strdup(frontApp.localizedName.UTF8String);
    }
}
```

Now you can just `#include "GetFrontApplication.h"` and call `GetFrontmostApplication()` from your C code, and you'll get a `char *` containing the name of the application. Make sure to `free()` the string after you're done with it.

Comment: it should work with a simple #include "GetFrontApplication.h" right? When I compile it I get a "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64" should I add something to the compiling instruction, other than "gcc -o front front.c "?

Comment: @Daniel At the very least you will need to compile both `front.c` and `GetFrontApplication.m`. You also need to link against the Cocoa framework, but since I used `@import`, that should automatically happen as long as you use `-fmodules` in the command line. So, something like: `gcc -fmodules -o front front.c GetFrontApplication.m` should do it.